# Shared parts between 97 Toyota Camry and 97 Lexus ES300

Tags: camry, lexus, part-interchange

I'm looking to source used parts to try a repair for my car, which is a *1997 Lexus ES300*. This is mainly for self-learning as I'm not familiar with DIY car repairs.

Since Camry components are far easier to find, I was wondering if the following components are similar enough to substitute them:

**Interior**: Front cup holder, rear cup holder, overhead switch cover for interior lights.

**Engine system**: Charcoal canister, EVAP VSV, vacuum hoses for evaporator subsystem.

If there is a way to lookup equivalence for any component, that would be awesome to know for future reference.

Comment: If you have the part numbers, sites like Amazon (and I think Autozone) will let you see which vehicles that part # is compatible with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even for the same car model and generation (such as all 1997-01 Lexus ES300), not all parts will be interchangeable. For example, the passenger door switches or side moulding between windows in a 1999 ES300 are not compatible with a '97 model. Other minor issues are different color choices dependant on model year - e.g. rear cup holder exterior could be slightly different and impossible to fully fix without dyeing it.

I haven't completely confirmed this, but considering that most parts sites etc. don't even suggest pulling parts from a Camry to match an ES300, they have enough differences to where interior and smaller electrical systems don't match.

Probably, unless its a large homogenous building block like an engine, there is no chance of the Camry equivalent having the same layout to replace Lexus components.